# Uploading a file to a webservice without saving to server, database, or locally

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a web service that will let the user upload a file and then I will make some changes to the file and return the file. But I want to get that file content without saving it to the server, database, or locally. Instead I want to save the content into a stream or something similar so that I can then run modifications on its content and return the new file.

I have tried doing the following but can only figure out how to get it to upload and save locally. Currently the file information is collected from the form data and the file headers.

```
    namespace FileConverter.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/test")]
    public class FileUploadController : ApiController
    {
        private static readonly string ServerUploadFolder = "C:\\Temp"; //Path.GetTempPath();

        [Route("files")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateMimeMultipartContentFilter]
        public async Task<FileResult> UploadSingleFile()
        {
            var streamProvider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(ServerUploadFolder);
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);

            return new FileResult
            {
                FileNames = streamProvider.FileData.Select(entry => entry.LocalFileName),
                Names = streamProvider.FileData.Select(entry => entry.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName),
                ContentTypes = streamProvider.FileData.Select(entry => entry.Headers.ContentType.MediaType),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I use a ValidateMimeMultipartContentFilter attribute to check if the correct MIME type is sent.

```
namespace FileConverter.Controllers
{
    public class ValidateMimeMultipartContentFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (!actionContext.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
            }
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

I then have a model set up to store some data.

```
namespace FileConverter.Controllers
{
    public class FileResult
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> FileNames { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> ContentTypes { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Names { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can get the content of the file in a Stream/byte[] without saving the file locally and then reading its content? If so how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time your form action is invoked, ASP.NET has already done a lot of magic to interpret the file upload, so you can't really do much within the action itself. However, you can capture the byte streams in multipart forms as they come across the wire using an HttpModule or HttpHandler.

[This example](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2013/03/26/streaming-large-files-asynchronously-using-net-4-5/) seems like it would be a good starting point.

I don't know whether an HttpRequest can begin returning data until after the payload has been received, so this is likely going to require some crazy cross-request magic if you literally want to "stream" the filtering process. On the other hand, if you were intending to keep the whole file in memory while you process it and then send it back afterward, I'd argue that you're better off allowing MVC to save the file as a temp file: you'd potentially get worse performance by keeping the entire uploaded file in memory while it's being uploaded.

Comment: PS--Pay attention to Royi Namir's comment at the bottom of that example: while this is an example of using an Http Handler, the way this code is written doesn't take proper advantage of the `async` nature of the operations.